# SimpleXML не работает XPath при определенных атрибутах в корневом элементе

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

Не могу понять, как взаимодействовать с этой штукой.

```
$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<feed xmlns:at="http://purl.org/atompub/tombstones/1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"><at:deleted-entry ref="yt:video:9ubWtlFE_70" when="2017-11-21T01:24:21+00:00">
  <link href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9ubWtlFE_70"/>
  <at:by>
   <name>Yuna</name>
   <uri>https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCmKqEea12BLfuP-7yTMK3jw</uri>
  </at:by>
 </at:deleted-entry></feed>';

$simple_xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);
$xpath = $simple_xml->xpath('/feed');
var_dump($xpath);
```

результат: `array(0) {}`

Но если убрать атрибуты в корневом элементе, то тогда норм всё:

```
$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<feed><at:deleted-entry ref="yt:video:9ubWtlFE_70" when="2017-11-21T01:24:21+00:00">
  <link href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9ubWtlFE_70"/>
  <at:by>
   <name>Yuna</name>
   <uri>https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCmKqEea12BLfuP-7yTMK3jw</uri>
  </at:by>
 </at:deleted-entry></feed>';

$simple_xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);
$xpath = $simple_xml->xpath('/feed');
var_dump($xpath);
```

результат: `array(1) {...}`

Но крайне не хотелось бы через str_replace заменять атрибуты в корневом элементе - это же думать тогда придется, да и зачем тогда вообще использовать SimpleXML.

Comment: потому что по версии SimpleXML это неправильно сформированная XML-строка  https://repl.it/repls/HopefulAzureRabidsquirrel

Comment: @Jean-Claude, спасибо. Грустно теперь, правда, стало, но что ж поделать) Может подскажете - есть что-нибудь проще DOMDocument, чем можно разбирать такие xml-элементы?

Comment: есть и другие способы https://habrahabr.ru/post/330240/

Comment: @Jean-Claude, блин, видел даже эту статью недавно, и как-то в голове не отложилось совсем. Спасибо большое, попробую "XML Reader". Ответ-то напишете? а то, я так понимаю, вопрос останется висеть нерешенным.

Comment: `xmlns` - это не атрибуты, это пространства имён. Естественно, их нужно учитывать при работе с xml. [тыц](https://stackoverflow.com/q/595946/5045688)

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, а... вон оно че с ним надо было делать) может ответ оформите?